# Sentido original de «cuidar»

Tags: significado, vocabulário, diferenças-transatlânticas

O verbo ***cuidar*** no latim significava ***pensar***.

Apesar de constar no dicionário da RAE  com este sentido para o espanhol, ninguém o usa nem acho que entenderia se ouvisse. Mas mantém o significado na fala comum no asturiano, onde se usa em orações de forma *acho/acredito que* (*cuido que*).

Segundo o dicionário Priberam, o primeiro significado de *cuidar* é *pensar* mas eu nunca o li nem ouvi com este significado. Os luso-falantes modernos entendê-lo-ia? Se sim, quais são os aspectos sociolinguísticos do verbo usado assim? (registro/geografia/dialeto/idade, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

Em Portugal *cuidar* já não é usado correntemente com esse significado. E a minha primeira reação ao ler a primeira linha da tua pergunta, *O verbo cuidar no latim significava pensar", foi *o quê?!*. Depois lembrei-me de [O dia em que nasci moura e pereça](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ecfb/VdS/v057.txt) de Luís de Camões (porque o usei no outro dia numa resposta), que tem esta estrofe:

> As pessoas pasmadas, de ignorantes,
>
> As lágrimas no rosto, a cor perdida,
>
> Cuidem que o mundo já se destruiu.

Consultei o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, que inclui entre os significados *ter por certo, ser de opinião que*, e cita Camilo de Castelo Branco (1825-88). Ora eu até tenho lido recentemente obras de Camilo e doutros autores portugueses e brasileiros do século XIX, e não estava nada lembrado de *cuidar* com esse significado. Creio que em contexto compreenderia *cuidar*, e muitas outras pessoas, talvez a maioria, também.

Comment: Concordo com o Jacinto em contexto acho que se compreende.

Comment: Machado de Assis usa o termo esporadicamente em suas obras (por exemplo, em https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Dom_Casmurro/I ), então brasileiros mais lidos que têm o costume de consultar palavras desconhecidas no dicionário estarão familiarizados com a acepção, mas o uso numa situação cotidiana seria considerado pedante, como o @Centaurus escreveu.

Answer (score 3):

No Brasil, o verbo "cuidar", **no sentido de supor, imaginar, ou pensar**, quase nunca é usado. Contudo, e isto é uma opinião pessoal, a maioria das pessoas com grau de instrução superior entenderia o significado em contexto.  Eu já ouvi algumas vezes mas sempre em situações formais onde alguém falava para um público. Soa pedante para os que sabem o significado, e estranho para aqueles que tem de entender no contexto.  Acho que muitos brasileiros não entenderiam, principalmente os adolescentes e adultos jovens.

> Exemplos (Dicionário Aurélio, segunda edição)
>
> - "Cuidei que ele dormia, mas estava desperto."
> - "Cuidou maduramente o plano."